# react warning Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this button

```
<button
                className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-secondary has-icon"
                onClick={() => {
                  const idSelected = []

                  const itemSelected = this.state.clientItemUser.filter((i, row) => {

                    if (this.props.listTableCheckedItems.indexOf(row) === -1) {
                      idSelected.push(i.clientid)
                      return i
                    }
                  })

                  const { setTableCheckedItems } = this.props
                  console.log('itemSelected > ', itemSelected)
                  this.setState({ clientItemUser: itemSelected, clientIdItemUser: idSelected })

                  setTableCheckedItems([])
                }}
              >
```

it works and do what is suppoused to do, but i want to get rid of this warning "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return"
it says the problem is on the line `const itemSelected = this.state.clientItemUser.filter((i, row) =>` i really want to learn how to solve this warnings since its not the only place that it appears,i belive that understanding this one im going to be able to figure out the other ones, thanks for your time and help

i have looked another similar problems on stack but they dont seems to be the same as mine

Comment: As the error message tells you, the callback passed to `filter` should return something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only returning something in the case of `row` being in `this.props.listTableCheckedItems`.

There are a couple issues here.

1: You need to return something if that is not true.

```
if (this.props.listTableCheckedItems.indexOf(row) === -1) {
  idSelected.push(i.clientid)
  return i
} else {
  return ...
}
```

2: Your filter callback will return falsy for the first element in the list, since `i` is 0. Unless this is intended, you should return `true` or `false`.

```
if (this.props.listTableCheckedItems.indexOf(row) === -1) {
  idSelected.push(i.clientid)
}
return this.props.listTableCheckedItems.indexOf(row) === -1
```

Comment: thanks this solved my problem, yea i dont know how i didnt saw something so basic thanks